# Hide searchbar on specific route Angular6

Tags: html, angular

I want to display an input on my header when route is `/home` and hide it when it's something else. This is what I've tried by now, but it's not working properly.

.html

```
<div *ngIf="searchBarVisible">
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
</div>
```

.ts

```
searchBarVisible: boolean = false
constructor(private router: Router) {
    router.events.forEach((event) => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
        if (event['url'] == '/home') {
          this.searchBarVisible = true
        } else {
          this.searchBarVisible = false
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

Which seems to be the problem? Thank you for your time!

Comment: Are you gettting any errors?

Comment: Try to use NavigationStart in a resolver. I think they won't triggered because navigation has already stopped. add in some logs to see if the constructor starts and after each if to see where it stops.

Comment: No, the input is not visible, no matter on which route I am.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just check the **`router.url`**  as follows:

```
isHome(): boolean {
    const check = this.router.url.indexOf('/home');
    if (check) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

and then,

```
<div *ngIf="isHome()">
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
</div>
```